# How to check same position in two different lists in python

Tags: python, list, position

I am new to python.

I got two different list

```
 A = [0,0,0,0,0,20,40,0]  
 B = [0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0]
```

In list A it has values at position 5 & 6. So i want to get the corresponding values(which is 3 and 0) at position 5 & 6 in list B.

So could you please give me some advice regarding that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use enumerate along with list_comprehension.

```
>>> A = [0,0,0,0,0,20,40,0]
>>> B = [0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0]
>>> [B[i] for i,j in enumerate(A) if j != 0]
[3, 0]
>>> [B[i] for i,j in enumerate(A) if j]
[3, 0]
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Avinash Raj.

Answer (score 0):

Simply iterate over the list and check for non zero values.

```
A = [0,0,0,0,0,20,40,0]  
B = [0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0]
j = 0
for item in A:
    if item != 0:
        temp = B[j]
        print(temp)
        j = j+1
    else:
        j = j+1
```

Output:

3
0

Comment: Thank you @Divyanushu Kalra

Answer (score 0):

The solution with the list comprehensions is good, but hard to read for a beginner. The solution with the j iterator is good, but you can do the same thing using the built-in `enumerate()` function.

```
A = [0,0,0,0,0,20,40,0]    
B = [0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0]

for index, val in enumerate(A):
    if val != 0:
        temp = B[index]
        print(temp)
```

output `30`

Comment: Thank u @NotAnAmbiTurner

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> A = [0,0,0,0,0,20,40,0]  
>>> B = [0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0]
>>> [j for i, j in zip(A, B) if i]
[3, 0]
```

Comment: Thank u @John La Rooy